# Celery not publishing message to non-task based RabbitMQ Queue

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I'm trying to connect a Django Rest Framework backend to RabbitMQ using Celery. I have a few micro-services that use RabbitMQ as a message bus between the backend and those services. When I have the backend call a task that pushes a message to the micro-services message bus the message is never put into the queue for one of those services to grab. The queues I declare in my tasks.py are being created in RabbitMQ but are not being used by any of the producers.

**testcelery/celery.py**

```
...
from celery import Celery


os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "testcelery.settings")
app = Celery("testcelery")
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

**testcelery/settings.py**

```
...

installed_apps = [
...
"backend_processing"
]

CELERY_BROKER_URL = "amqp://testuser@rabbitmq_host:5672"
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ["application/json"]
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = "json"
```

**backend_processing/tasks.py**

```
...
from celery import shared_task
from testcelery.celery import app as celery_app
from kombu import Exchange, Queue

test_queue = Queue("test_queue", Exchange("test"), "test", durable=True)

@shared_task
def run_processing(data, producer=None):
    with celery_app.producer_or_acquire(producer) as producer:
        producer.publish(data,
                         declare=[test_queue],
                         retry=True,
                         exchange=test_queue.exchange,
                         routing_key=test_queue.routing_key,
                         delivery_mode="persistent")
```

What do I need to modify in my configuration to allow celery to publish to queues other than the ones given to celery by the settings.py?

Comment: `backend_processing` is the app name registered in Django?

Comment: Yes backend_processing is in my settings.py file